# Как правильно вернуть значение массива из метода?

Tags: java, массивы

Когда делаю возврат значения массива из метода, то в консоли пишет какую-то абракадабру, такого типа `[I@1540e19d`. Если пишу `return Arrays.toString(numbers);` то Идея подсвечивает красным. А как правильно в `return` записать, чтобы содержимое массива распечаталось нормально?

```
public static int[] findNumbers(String text){

    String[] words = text.trim().split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

    int[] numbers = new int[words.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        try {
            numbers[index] = Integer.valueOf(words[i]);
            System.out.println("Index " + index + " - Number " + numbers[index]);
            index++;
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("not a number");
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Массив нельзя просто так вывести. В цикле выводить нужно. Либо ArrayList юзать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возвращаете вы его правильно. Но видимо не правильно печатаете. Должно быть примерно так

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findNumbers("12 13 14")));
```

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, точно, я не там Arrays.toString применял. Спасибо за помощь.